# How to print stack trace without error occurance

Tags: java

Say I have method "a" inside which I have a if condition and in the else block of this if ,I just print log.warn("predefined message"). I want to print stack trace to get where exactly this method is being called and condition got failed.

sudo

```
enter code here

class test{
 testa(){
   if(condition is true){
       //do the stuff
     }else {
  log.warn("condition failed "); 
  }
   }
      }
```

I want to print stack trace with log.warn.(I don't want to use Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace(),any other way to do this whitout using Threads)

Comment: Why dont you throw and catch an exception then log it using logger?

Comment: new Exception().printStackTrace();

Comment: `log.warn("Condition failed.", new Exception())`

Comment: If I use try catch and then throw , the logging level of the error should be changed in my application, I don't want to increased log level here.

Comment: Thanks Boris the Spider , this gave me an Idea .

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`.

Comment: This seems like a better approach. However this line from java docs confuses me a little: `In the extreme case, a virtual machine that has no stack trace information concerning this thread is permitted to return a zero-length array from this method`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [`Throwable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#Throwable--) (note that I'm not saying *throw* one, just create it) and call [`fillInStackTrace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#fillInStackTrace--)*, then use [`getStackTrace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace--) (or whatever you want to do at that point).

* I *think* you need to call `fillInStackTrace`, but the constructor docs seem to suggest the constructor will call it, which makes me wonder why it would be a public method. I'm probably just tired.